# Copy entire row to a new Excel sheet (locate in MS Teams) tab based on a single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet located in MS Teams that we use to collect data from two sources. The first data is input from a form (also in teams) that staff complete. Once this data is dumped into tab 1 of the sheet, there is an active VLOOKUP that looks in tab 2 which contains data that has been imported manually from our company database.

I have three criteria set up on tab 1 (column L):

- Complete
- Incomplete
- Nil Found

What I want to do is work out a formula that will recognise what category that row belongs in (based on column L) then copy that whole row & paste it into a new tab, which are called Complete, Incomplete & Nil Found.

My issue is, every solution I find requires Visual Basic which is not supported in MS Teams. so I am looking to see if there is in fact a way to do this without it being a manual process I have to undertake every day.

Comment: An easy manual solution is: Filter by criteria copy filtered table paste in new sheet. Alternatively check power query (not sure if this is available in teams).

Comment: Manual solution isn't helpful unfortunately as this is a sheet that is being updated constantly so manual copy paste would be an all day job for someone. It really needs to be automatic so I can set & forget as it were!

Comment: Well if power query isn't available in teams (you need to check this, bc I don't know if it is available or not) then I don't see this automation to happen.